# Putting Four distinct Stickers on Three Different Balls Such that stickers are infinite supply and one sticker each ball, and Exactly Two Same Sticker

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> We have three distinct balls (representing the people here) and we have an unlimited supply of four different types of stickers - S, M, T, W (representing the different days / birthdays). In how many ways can each ball be labeled with a sticker such that exactly two balls have the same type of sticker. Will the answer be different if the balls were identical?

> If the balls are *distinct*, the answer would be

> $${4 \choose 1} \cdot {3 \choose 2} \cdot {3 \choose 1} = 36$$

> Any of the four sticker types can be the repeating one ${4 \choose 1}$, any two of the three balls can share the same type ${3 \choose 2}$, and finally, the last ball can get any of the remaining three types ${3 \choose 1}$.

You can only have a total of two colors on the three balls. If you did Three choose two then Three choose 1 wouldn't you count a total of three colors on the three balls? Why not

$$ {4 \choose 1} \cdot { 3 \choose 1}?$$ Doesn't this expression mean:

You’re putting the two balls into the bin with one color and one ball into the bin with two possible colors hence only a single three choose one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers are both correct, but your explanation for the indistinguishable balls case does not make sense.  You should have four bins, one for each color.  You can correct your attempt by selecting which of the four bins receives two balls and which of the remaining three bins receives one ball.

We must select one of the four colors to place on two of the indistinguishable balls.  Since the balls are indistinguishable, it does not matter on which two balls we place that color.  That leaves us with a choice of which of the three remaining colors to place on the remaining ball.  Hence, there are indeed
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}$$
to place three stickers on three balls so that each ball receives one sticker, exactly two of the balls receive a sticker of the same color, and there are four colors available, each of which can be selected as many times as needed.

Comment: This is the identical case right? The op's question has led me to believe he was confused on the distinct ones, though the phrasing is ambiguous

Comment: @sanya  The OP's explanation of the case with distinct balls is correct, so I focused on the case with indistinguishable balls.

Comment: Oh!!!!! I thought that above para was him quoting his book and the solution it provided. Im sorry. Thankyou for the clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

**Distinct case**:
(which im presuming youre confused about)
Let the three balls be represented as B1 B2 B3.

For now lets assume the first 2 balls (B1B2) as 1 big ball sharing the same type of sticker. Iff you do that, you essentially have 4 options for the first big ball, and 3 options for the next ball. Therefore 4*3=12.

Next do it again for B2B3, the next two balls sharing the same sticker.  You get 12 again

And lastly for the  first and the last ball, B1B3, sharing the same sticker. You get 12 again.

12+12+12=36

**Identical case**:
If all the three balls are indistinguishable and cannot be told apart then i would like for you to imagine it as BBB.

We're going to take two balls(any two here as all are same) and consider it as one big ball again. Now you just need to put two stickers out of the 4 on these 2 balls(One big ball and the other leftover ball). There are again 4 optional stickers for the first big ball and 3 for the next:
4*3=12